# passing parameter in has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I have a class `Test, Question, Testquestion` associated by `has_many through`

```
class Test
  has_many :testquestions
  has_many :questions, through: :testquestions
end

class Question
  has_many :testquestions
  has_many :tests, through: :testquestions
end

class Testquestion
  belongs_to :test
  belongs_to :questions
end
```

While creating a `Test` i want to pass a value of column `order` of `Testquestion`.

```
def create
   Test.create(test_params)
end

def test_params
  params.require(:test).permit(:testname,question_attributes:[:questionname])
end
```

How should i pass value of `order` column so that associated model(Testquestion) get updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do it that way, you will need to take a longer path.

1. Don't forget to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to your assossiations, so that nested operations would actualy work.
2. Check that you have added `accepts_nested_attributes_for :question` to `Testquestion`.
3. Get your params structured right.

Something like this:

```
{
  test: {
    testname: 'someName',
    testquestion_attributes: {
      order: someOrder,
      question_attributes: {
        questionname: 'someName'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

4. Require your params.

`params.require(:test).permit(:testname, testquestion_params: [:id, :order, :_destroy, question_params: [:id, :questionname])`

p.s. sidenote: you should really aquire  a habbit of naming your fields and variables in `snake_case` and your classes in `CamelCase`.